# OpenGL ES 2.0 GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT and glTexImage2D

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

The Chapter 12 of `OpenGL ES 2.0 programming guide` book has an example, which called `Example 12-2 Render to Depth Texture`.
This example calls glTexImage2D API, and the `internalformat` parameter is GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT.

But using GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT is not allowed according to https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml.

So I have 2 questions about OpenGL ES 2.0.

- If the example is not proper, how to render to depth texture? If the example is proper, why not match the description of `www.khronos.org`?
- Which API will use GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT enumeration?

Comment: If you've found an error, please consult http://www.opengles-book.com/es2/errata.html

Comment: Sorry, the example is proper. Because there is a condition. `In Example 12-2 we look at how to use a depth texture as
a depth buffer attachment to framebuffer. This feature is available if the
OES_depth_texture extension is supported by the implementation.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which API will use GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT enumeration?

[glRenderbufferStorage](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glRenderbufferStorage.xml) uses `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT`, specifically `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16`

```
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, (GLuint*)&_nRenderTargetRboDepthId);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _nRenderTargetRboDepthId);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, nTexWidth, nTexHeight);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _nRenderTargetRboDepthId);

    GLenum err = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if(err != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) { // error!
         // format harddrive
    }
```

Comment: Only GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16 can be used for glRenderbufferStorage. Please click the link you provided and check it.

Comment: My apologies, I answered the second question you asked `Which API will use GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT enumeration?` and then pasted working code.

Comment: I know, but glRenderbufferStorage only receive GL_RGBA4, GL_RGB565, GL_RGB5_A1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, or GL_STENCIL_INDEX8. There is no GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT.

Comment: Ok, so ask yourself what exactly is `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT`.  How many bits does it use?  16?  24?  32?  On OpenGLES2, is uses 16.  Do you know how I know it uses 16?  Because it is very explicit.  There is no `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT` because is is too vague, and `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16` is precise.

Comment: gl2.h only define GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT and GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16. GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT is used for PixelFormat, and GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16 is used for Framebuffer/Renderbuffer Object. glRenderbufferStorage can use GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16. It's OK. I confused about GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, how to use it.

Comment: The long and short of it is you probably want to migrate to OpenGL ES 3 to get what you want.  https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml  Extensions aren't supported everywhere, and IIRC, it doesn't work on iOS.